# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Если я пишу так:

```
render() {
    let a = this.state.table
    for (var key in a) {
        console.log("Key:", key)
        console.log("Value:", a[key])
    }
    ...
}
```

То все работает правильно и выводит

```
KEY: 0
Value: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "tr", key: "3", ref: null, props: {…}, …}
```

А так:

```
render() {
    let a = this.state.table
    a[0] = some_thing \\ a['0'] = some_thing  .table тоже
    ...
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of null (react-dom.development.js:25193)
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: `a[0] = this.state.table` - ??

Comment: @Igor, просто для примера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` вызывается несколько раз. В один из этих разов (первый?) `this.state.table` равно `null`. Цикл по свойствам `null`-объекта не выполняет ни одной итерации, поэтому Вы его не видите в консоли.

```js
var a = null;
console.log("before for");
for (var key in a) {
  console.log("Key:", key)
  console.log("Value:", a[key])
}
console.log("after for");
```